# Use iframe to browse internet

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to create a mini browser in a html page by iframe:

```
<table id="frame" height="100%" width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>Enter the address: 
      <label for="address"></label>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
    <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Go"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but I do not know how to get the address value and put instead of google.com, how to do that with html or javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `src` attribute from Javascript using an `id` to retrieve the `iframe` node.

```
Address: <input id="address">
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="visit()">
<br>
<iframe id="my_iframe"></iframe>
<script>
    function visit() {
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        document.getElementById("my_iframe").src = address;
    }
</script>
```

Note however that there is a large number of sites that won't allow you to visit them this way. The reasons are complex (and IMO somewhat idiotic), but the point remains that it's not a technique that can be used in general.

Comment: @amir `onclick="visit()"` inside the button tag.
or in JS: `document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", visit);`

Answer (score 1):

Set an ID attribute to your `iframe`

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" id="frame_id" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Use this JS:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('frame_id');
var addressBar = document.getElementById("address");
var button = document.getElementById("go");

button.addEventListener("click", reload);

function reload() {
    frame.contentWindow.location.href = addressBar.value;
    frame.contentWindow.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JavaScript (jQuery) code:

```
$(function() {
  var iframe = $('#my-iframe-id');
  var oldurl = iframe.attr('src'); // to get the url
  var newurl = 'http://myurl';
  iframe.attr('src', newurl); // to set the url
});
```